# GRUB ругается на диск, которого нету

Tags: grub, archlinux, lvm

Пытаюсь установить GRUB (дистрибутив - Arch Linux):

```
root@archiso: ~ # arch-chroot /mnt
root@archlinux: / # grub-install --force /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform
grub-install: error: disk 'lvmid/nonexistent-uuid' not found
```

`rmmod floppy` в хосте не спас (ох уж этот QEMU, который подсунул /dev/fd0).
При том, что UUID, на который ругается GRUB, не существует. И что делать?

Оказалось, что "несуществующий UUID" - это UUID vg0 (/dev/vg0/...) Только какого черта на него ругается, если я до этого спокойно ставил и нормальные дистрибутивы aka Linux Lite на шифрованные разделы...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка такая:

```
 ~ # cfdisk /dev/sda
# /dev/sda1 1G unformatted
# /dev/sda2 32G unformatted
 ~ # cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda1 --type luks1
# GRUB не понимает LUKS2
 ~ # cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda2
 ~ # cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 b
 ~ # cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 r
 ~ # pvcreate /dev/mapper/b
 ~ # pvcreate /dev/mapper/r
 ~ # vgcreate vg0 /dev/mapper/b
 ~ # vgcreate vg1 /dev/mapper/r
 ~ # lvcreate -n boot -L 1G vg0
 ~ # lvcreate -n root-btrfs -L 32G vg1
 ~ # mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg0/boot
 ~ # mkfs.btrfs /dev/vg1/root-btrfs
 ~ # mount -t btrfs /dev/vg1/root-btrfs /mnt
 ~ # btrfs subvolume create /mnt/root-main
 ~ # btrfs subvolume set-default /root-main /mnt
 ~ # umount /mnt
 ~ # mount -t btrfs /dev/vg1/root-btrfs /mnt
 ~ # mkdir -p /mnt/boot
 ~ # mount -t ext4 /dev/vg0/boot /mnt/boot
 ~ # pacstrap /mnt
```

Comment: Это LVM внутри LUKS? Версия LUKS1 или LUKS2? Расскажите как разметку делали, чтобы мы могли повторить?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.